# Select all ended bookings

Tags: mysql, sql, select

We have a series of Bookings in our database, every Booking has one Sequence of multiple Sessions. Every Session has a 'stop' which contains a DateTime.

I want to select the bookings in which all sessions have ended between two dates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
  FROM Booking as b
    JOIN Sequence as se
    JOIN Session as s
ON (b.sequence_id=se.id AND s.sequence_id=se.id
    AND s.stop between '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-01 00:00:00');
```

This SQL selects the bookings that contain 1 or more ended sessions.

I only want the bookings in which all sessions are ended.

Any ideas?

Comment: Either modify your join or add another and select for isnull(s.stop). IE look for stops missing the end date.

Comment: 'stop' is never null in the database. 'stop' in every Session has to be between two timestamps for the booking to be selected.

Comment: How do you know if a given Session has not been stopped? What's the default value when Session is created?

Comment: 'stop' is the expected end date. It is always set while creating a Session.

Comment: I think I get it: select for sessions that don't have any entries that exist outside of the date range?

Comment: Correct, I need the bookings with sessions that don't have any entries that exist outside of the date range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you could do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*  
  FROM Booking as b  
  JOIN Sequence as se  
  JOIN Session as s  
     ON (b.sequence_id=se.id AND s.sequence_id=se.id )  
  where s.stop between '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-01 00:00:00')  
     and not exists ( s.stop < '2012-09-01 00:00:00' )  
     and not exists ( s.stop > '2012-12-01 00:00:00');
```

The syntax isn't quite right though.

Answer (score 2):

thanx, the exact query goes like this:

```
SELECT b.id, s.stop  
  FROM Booking as b  
  JOIN Sequence as se  
  JOIN Session as s  
     ON (b.sequence_id=se.id AND s.sequence_id=se.id)  
        where not exists (SELECT ss.id from Session as ss where ss.sequence_id=se.id and ss.stop < '2012-09-01 00:00:00')  
        and not exists (SELECT ss.id from Session as ss where ss.sequence_id=se.id and ss.stop > '2012-12-01 00:00:00');
```